# Referencing shell32 for unzip file works good for w7 but not for xp

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Hi i use that for unzipping files to a directory

```
private string UnzipFile(string inputFileName, string destinationPath)
{
    Shell shell = new ShellClass();
    Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(inputFileName);
    Folder folder2 = shell.NameSpace(destinationPath);
    string name = folder.Items().Item(0).Name;
    folder2.CopyHere(folder.Items(), "");
    return name;
}
```

when i compile the project it gives me also interop.shell32.dll

and i merge interop.shell32.dll with my executable file by ilmerge

(i compile @ win 7 vs 12)

but unzipfile function crashes program @ Windows xp sp2

any idea why it does?

Comment: "It crashes" is not an adequate description of the problem.  You must document the exact exception message you see to get help.  If you don't have one then you'll need to improve the unhandled exception reporting in your program first.

Comment: @L.E. i think i was used another lib like 7zip